# Datagridview column showing System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` populated by data from my database.

I have 3 columns on my database table: `id, name, status.` However these are all in text/string format.

Based on the data I get from the status column of my database(Online or Offline), I try to place an image on the cell, instead of just a plain Online or Offline string.

I attached my `DGV` to the `DataBindingComplete` event. Currently have this code:

```
void DataGridView1DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {   
            if (r.Cells["status"].Value.ToString() == "Online")
            {
                // add online image here
                r.Cells["status"].Value = Resource1.MyOnlineIcon;
            }
            else if(r.Cells["status"].Value.ToString() == "Offline")
            {
                // add offline image here
                r.Cells["status"].Value = Resource1.MyOfflineIcon;
            }

        }
```

But the problem is that it shows `System.Drawing.Bitmap` on the cell, instead of actually displaying the picture. Since in my database, the data type for the status column is string, the DGV also makes the column of string type. How do I change the existing string/text type column to an image column? What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: How are you binding the data from the database?

Comment: By using an sql command, I get the data from database and store it in a dataset. Then I set the datagridview.Source to the dataset.Tables[0]

Comment: Could you add that code to the question? Also, I don't think the `DataBindingComplete` event is an appropriate place to modify cell contents. Preferably the conversion from `string` to `Bitmap` is done before the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert your database query to a Collection of objects like this

```
public class SomeObject {
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Bitmap Image {get;set;

    public SomeObject(int id, string name, string status) {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Image = status == "Online" ? Resource1.MyOnlineIcon : Resource1.MyOfflineIcon;
    }

}
```

It should work just fine by binding it to the `DataGridView`:

```
List<SomeObject> source = dbConnection.GetObjects();
dataGridView.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This gave me an idea how to solve the problem. Got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [DataGridViewImageColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to display the image in DataGridViewCell.

Am not sure whether you can set the column type for existing columns(I believe not possible). Anyhow, you can manually create columns by setting `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns` to false.

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewImageColumn
                            {
                               DataPropertyName = "YourImageColumnName",
                               Name = "status"
                            });

dataGridView1.DataSource = yourDataSource;
```

Comment: I have my Datagridview populated by data from my database, using a dataset. As a result, I get text/string column types. How do I change the existing column type to a DataGridViewImageColumn?

Comment: @Downvoter please leave a comment, so that I'll know where am wrong.

Comment: `ColumnName` isn't a valid for DataGridViewImageColumn. It is `dataGridView.DataSource`. Also, it doesn't seem to work at all.